# How do you change observations iteratively in R?

Tags: r, loops, date, dplyr, lubridate

How do you take duplicate rows and change them iteratively?

Given this hypothetical table which lists year repeating 12 times, how do you conditionally change it so that each year is now a date for each Student (iterating through the months)?

This is the beginning table:

| Student | Date | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Walton | 2018 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018 | .77 |
| Sam | 2018 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018 | .86 |

End table:

| Store | Date | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Walton | 2018-01-01 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018-02-01 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018-03-01 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018-04-01 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018-05-01 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018-06-01 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018-07-01 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018-08-01 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018-09-01 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018-10-01 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018-11-01 | .77 |
| Walton | 2018-12-01 | .77 |
| Sam | 2018-01-01 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018-02-01 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018-03-01 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018-04-01 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018-05-01 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018-06-01 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018-07-01 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018-08-01 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018-09-01 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018-10-01 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018-11-01 | .86 |
| Sam | 2018-12-01 | .86 |

Have attempted function using `case_when` which did not work. Sorry if this has already been asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a sequence of date starting on the 1st of January, with 1 month intervals, and length as the number of observations per group.

```r
df %>% 
   group_by(Student) %>% 
   mutate(Date = seq(as.Date(ISOdate(first(Date), 1, 1)), by = '1 month', length.out = n()))

   Student Date       Grade
   <chr>   <date>     <dbl>
 1 Walton  2018-01-01  0.77
 2 Walton  2018-02-01  0.77
 3 Walton  2018-03-01  0.77
 4 Walton  2018-04-01  0.77
 5 Walton  2018-05-01  0.77
 6 Walton  2018-06-01  0.77
 7 Walton  2018-07-01  0.77
 8 Walton  2018-08-01  0.77
 9 Walton  2018-09-01  0.77
10 Walton  2018-10-01  0.77
# ... with 14 more rows
```

If you can manually add the date, then use:

```r
seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), by = '1 month', length.out = n())
```

If you know that there are going to be twelve observations per group, use:

```r
seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-01"))
```

---

Using `lubridate`, another option is to use the `%m+%` operator:

```
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
   group_by(Student) %>% 
   mutate(Date = ymd(first(Date), truncated = 2) %m+% months(c(0:11)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `data.table` package :

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)
dt <- fread("
Student Date    Grade
Walton  2018    .77
Walton  2018    .77
Walton  2018    .77
Walton  2018    .77
Walton  2018    .77
Walton  2018    .77
Walton  2018    .77
Walton  2018    .77
Walton  2018    .77
Walton  2018    .77
Walton  2018    .77
Walton  2018    .77
Sam 2018    .86
Sam 2018    .86
Sam 2018    .86
Sam 2018    .86
Sam 2018    .86
Sam 2018    .86
Sam 2018    .86
Sam 2018    .86
Sam 2018    .86
Sam 2018    .86
Sam 2018    .86
Sam 2018    .86")

dt[,Month := 1:.N, by = Student] %>%
  .[, NewDate := make_date (Date, Month, 1)]
```

Here is the result :

```
> dt
    Student Date Grade Month    NewDate
 1:  Walton 2018  0.77     1 2018-01-01
 2:  Walton 2018  0.77     2 2018-02-01
 3:  Walton 2018  0.77     3 2018-03-01
 4:  Walton 2018  0.77     4 2018-04-01
 5:  Walton 2018  0.77     5 2018-05-01
 6:  Walton 2018  0.77     6 2018-06-01
 7:  Walton 2018  0.77     7 2018-07-01
 8:  Walton 2018  0.77     8 2018-08-01
 9:  Walton 2018  0.77     9 2018-09-01
10:  Walton 2018  0.77    10 2018-10-01
11:  Walton 2018  0.77    11 2018-11-01
12:  Walton 2018  0.77    12 2018-12-01
13:     Sam 2018  0.86     1 2018-01-01
14:     Sam 2018  0.86     2 2018-02-01
15:     Sam 2018  0.86     3 2018-03-01
16:     Sam 2018  0.86     4 2018-04-01
17:     Sam 2018  0.86     5 2018-05-01
18:     Sam 2018  0.86     6 2018-06-01
19:     Sam 2018  0.86     7 2018-07-01
20:     Sam 2018  0.86     8 2018-08-01
21:     Sam 2018  0.86     9 2018-09-01
22:     Sam 2018  0.86    10 2018-10-01
23:     Sam 2018  0.86    11 2018-11-01
24:     Sam 2018  0.86    12 2018-12-01
    Student Date Grade Month    NewDate
```

Comment: You can also replace Date column by assigning the variable name Date. NewDate is just for demo.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `dplyr` approach:

`mutate` a helper column `x` with 1 to 12,

`paste` it together and wrap it around `as.Date`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(x = rep(1:12, length.out = n()),
         Date = as.Date(paste(Date,x,"01",sep = "-")), .keep="unused")
```

```
Student       Date Grade
1   Walton 2018-01-01  0.77
2   Walton 2018-02-01  0.77
3   Walton 2018-03-01  0.77
4   Walton 2018-04-01  0.77
5   Walton 2018-05-01  0.77
6   Walton 2018-06-01  0.77
7   Walton 2018-07-01  0.77
8   Walton 2018-08-01  0.77
9   Walton 2018-09-01  0.77
10  Walton 2018-10-01  0.77
11  Walton 2018-11-01  0.77
12  Walton 2018-12-01  0.77
13     Sam 2018-01-01  0.86
14     Sam 2018-02-01  0.86
15     Sam 2018-03-01  0.86
16     Sam 2018-04-01  0.86
17     Sam 2018-05-01  0.86
18     Sam 2018-06-01  0.86
19     Sam 2018-07-01  0.86
20     Sam 2018-08-01  0.86
21     Sam 2018-09-01  0.86
22     Sam 2018-10-01  0.86
23     Sam 2018-11-01  0.86
24     Sam 2018-12-01  0.86
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! Very much appreciate it!